# Shortcut to edit title after slide creation in Libreoffice Impress

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, libreoffice

After a new slide is created using `Alt+i+e`, What keyboard shortcut can I use to jump to the title, or select it, for editing?

Comment: `esc + tab` seems to work sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is addressed in the LibreOffice Impress wiki, specifically [here](https://help.libreoffice.org/Impress/Using_Shortcut_Keys_in_Impress#To_Select_an_Object).

First enter the document using `CMD + Ctrl + F6`. Then, `Tab` to select the object you want, in this case the title, and press `Enter`.